# JavaScript perform action before closing tab

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some problems performing some actions before client closes tab or browser. I'm using Vue, and I would need to send HTTP request to my backend to perform some action.
I know that Vue has function `beforeDestroy()` and I have it implemented, but it can't perform that action if client closes tab or browser.
I tried to do something like:

```
created() {
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.leaveOrder())
    },
```

But still no success.
Does anyone have any idea how could I fix that problem?

btw: leaveOrder function is simple post request that looks like:

```
leaveOrder () {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                this.$http.post("/order/" + this.order.id + '/leave').then(response => {
                        console.log('Leaving')
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log('Something bad happeneds')
                    });
                resolve(true)
            })
        },
```

Comment: You can use [sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) though it's usually disabled nowadays because of privacy concerns

Comment: what about `window.addEventListener('unload', this.leaveOrder())`?

Comment: Already tried, no success